# Consume WCF service over the internet using wshttpbinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

basically ive followed this tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318810/WCF-Service-Method-Level-Security-using-Message-Co)

and have everything up and running and working fine off my local machine. I have deployed it in IIS and allowed necessary Firewall ports so off i go to my client PC which resides on a different domain.

I fired up the WCF Test client on this machine and typed in the URL for the WSDL and i was able to view the service calls no problem. Only thing is when i actually try to use the method and send off my values i get the following response

**"The Caller Was Not Authenticated By The Service"**

Weird - even though it still works locally it wont work on another machine. Is there a specific way to configure the client based on what im doing??

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF33.Service1">
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCF33.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/WCF33/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The tutorial i followed passes a key in the message header and authenticates based on that but thats not the issue. I think its something to do with the wshttp binding but i do need this type of encryption.

can anyone give me any info/advice on how to resolve this please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i now have this sorted, i had two main issues with this, this question actually ended up being my first hurdle.

With wshttpbinding i had to configure a client programatically, creating a wshttpbinding and attaching it to an instance of the service. I also had to pass windows credentials. Once i did this, the caller was authenticated message disappeared.

The next stage of the error was a application/xml error where the expected response didnt match soap 1.2 formatting. This was a strange one because for some reason even though the binding server side was wshttp, it was defaulting to basichttp on deployment. To get around this there is a mapping section in the wcf config editor where you can map protocols to a binding. In this, http is set to basichttp, simply change this to wshttp an you are good to go :)

hope this helps someone because these two errors seem to be everywhere with no answers at all!!

Answer (score 0):

> The tutorial i followed passes a key in the message header and authenticates based on that but thats not the issue.

Are you passing the key in your call?  If the code you have running is expecting something in the authentication header and it's not there that could cause that error to return.

Comment: yeah i'm passing it its expecting SEC00001 otherwise the return would be "You are not allowed to access this service"